# Ломается блок авторизации при масштабировании окна в браузере

Tags: html, css

При масштабировании окна в браузере ломается блок авторизации, перепробовал кучу всего, ничего не выходит.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<style>
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
}

H1 {
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

.container {
    width: 15%;
    padding: 2%;
    background: linear-gradient(MediumBlue, SteelBlue);
    margin: 3% auto;
    border-radius: 7%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40%;
    font-size: 60%;


}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 7%;
    margin: 0.5% 0 6% 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 4%;
}

.registerbtn {
    background: linear-gradient(LightSkyBlue, DodgerBlue);
    color: white;
    padding: 5% 10%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 60%;
    border-radius: 7%;
    font-size: 200%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5%;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/hello.php">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>C3000-HUB</h1>
    <p>s/n MadiHub</p>

    <input type="text" placeholder="login" name="login" required>

    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" required>

    <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Войти</button>
  </div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Окно авторизации]

Comment: Почитайте про медиа-запросы

Comment: У Вас все величины в %, при уменьшении экрана, ширина будет меньше, а не стабильна, как с `px`, например.

Comment: @entithat да, вы правы, совсем забыл об этом, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как ваша форма достаточно небольшая по размеру, то думаю можно сразу ей задать ширину статичной переменной. В противном случае можете сделать через [@media](https://html5book.ru/css3-mediazaprosy/) что бы при масштабировании экрана изменялись первоначально заданные стили.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}

H1 {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 12rem;
  padding: 2%;
  background: linear-gradient(MediumBlue, SteelBlue);
  margin: 3% auto;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40%;
  font-size: 60%;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 7%;
  margin: 0.5% 0 6% 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.registerbtn {
  background: linear-gradient(LightSkyBlue, DodgerBlue);
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.75rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60%;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  font-size: 200%;
  margin-bottom: 0.5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body>

  <form action="/hello.php">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>C3000-HUB</h1>
      <p>s/n MadiHub</p>

      <input type="text" placeholder="login" name="login" required>

      <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" required>

      <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Войти</button>
    </div>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```